# Vary: Accept-Encoding Response Header

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, browser

I am trying to understand the response Header "Vary: Accept-Encoding".

I am noticing the response header "Vary: Accept-Encoding" appears for some of the images in the developer tools for our application, but some images doesn't have this response header.

When i tried to hit same image url in the browser, not seeing this header "Vary: Accept-Encoding".

Why this header appears only for selected images in our application? What could be possibilities?

Comment: Hmm. The payloads do not *vary* for some of the images?

Comment: No, I am not seeing any change in the image by viewing the application.

Comment: I would recommend to read RFC 7231 sections related to content negotiation and compression encodings.

Answer (score 0):

Either Tomcat or the application could be returning this header. If Tomcat is applying e.g. `gzip` encoding, then it's essential to respond with a `Vary: Accept-Encoding` because if the client doesn't specify that it supports `gzip` then the origin server (web server), a proxy, etc. must respond with a different type of data.

If the client requests `/myapp/something` and advertises that it is willing to accept only responses with encoding `gzip`, then `/myapp/something` should really only return a response in the `identity` or `gzip` encodings, or reply with a 412 response.

The `Vary` header is really for proxies. It tells a proxy that clients on the other side might get a different response if they have different `Accept-Encoding` values in their request headers. So, if two clients request the same resource, but one says `Accept-Encoding: identity,gzip` and the other says `Accept-Encoding: identity,compress`, they will (likely) get two responses, and the proxy should understand that it's not just the URL that is important, but *also* the `Accept-Encoding` of the client that should govern any caching that the proxy might want to provide.

Comment: a) it always could return the un-encoded (uncompressed) variant. (b) replace "proxy" by "cache" - might be client-side...